# notifyItemChanged is consumed by custom observer in recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout

[Custom RecyclerView link](https://gist.github.com/TheGreat0004/7c9007e0cf8cf49a773c)

I have a created a custom recyclerview and it works fine, but the issues is that when i am updating an item, the notifydatasetchanged is intercepted by custom recyclerview observers and is not reflected into recycler view adapter but on scrolling the recyclervew the view gets update.

When i update any item and call notifydatasetchanged(),notifydatasetchanged() is intercepted by custom recyclerview adapter and is not reflected into my custom adapter
I don't know what to do, please assist me

Comment: what's the real problem

Comment: @VivekMishra, the adapter is not updating but on scroll it gets updated

Comment: Is this device dependent bug or common?

Comment: @konunger, it's common, not a device dependent bug